# Need to stress test an Angular application with weird login

Tags: angular, jmeter

I've been asked to perform a load test on an existing angular application I haven't wrote myself. I've tried using Jmeter but after some digging I've discovered that the login form doesn't perform any real check on any source but just a match on entered username / password.

Passing on that thing, that's not the scope of this question... I've seen that those informations are stored inside a localstorage on browser, but Jmeter not beign a browser doesn't read them. Is there any other tool I can use to call 5-10 times a page, evenutally perform the login (I don't have any particilular url for the login phase) (maybe looking at the page content) and then  perform the log on the page?

Thanks

#UPDATE #1

Hello,
I've discorvered that I can call the API even if I'm not logged so this discussion can be closed

Thanks

Comment: This kind of testing is usually done on an API, to see its limits. I don't see the point of testing if the JS on the user's browser is going to hold ...

Answer (score 0):

If "login" doesn't trigger any [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - there is no need to simulate it with JMeter, just proceed with the following steps. However I would suggest double checking this using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or recording the login process using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

The approach to validate credentials against local storage is kind of strange because if you launch another browser (or the same browser in [incognito mode](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3356840/how-to-go-incognito-in-chrome-firefox-safari-and-edge.html)) the local storage will be empty and there won't be any credentials there.